# trimming log file between two line

Tags: python, datetime, trim, logfile

I writing one python script to trim log file between two line.

here is the I have written:

```
import optparse
import datetime

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f","--file",dest="log_file",
                          action="store",help="Specify log file to be parsed")
options, args = parser.parse_args()
vLogFile=options.log_file

start_time = raw_input("Please enter start time:\n[Format: HH:MM]=")
end_time = raw_input("Please enter end time:\n[Format: HH:MM]=")
trim_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d%H%M%S')
output_file = 'trimmed_log_%s.txt' %trim_time
with open(vLogFile) as file:
    for vline in file:
        vDate = vline[0:10]
        break
    start_line = vDate + ' ' + start_time
    end_line = vDate + ' ' +end_time
    print("Start time:%s" %start_line)
    print("End time:%s" %end_line)
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if line.startswith(start_line):
            start_line_number = num
            break
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if line.startswith(end_line):
            end_line_number = num
            break
    file.close()
print(start_line_number,end_line_number)
with open(vLogFile,"r") as file:
    oFile = open(output_file,'a')
    for num, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if num >= start_line_number and num <= end_line_number:
            oFile.write(line)
print("%s Created" %output_file)
```

Below is the result of a script:

```
$ python trim.py -f ErrorLog.txt
Please enter start time:
[Format: HH:MM]=16:16
Please enter end time:
[Format: HH:MM]=16:29
Start time:2017-11-12 16:16
End time:2017-11-12 16:29
(333, 2084)
trimmed_log_23063222.txt Created
```

Here start line(333) is correct but end line(2084) is incorrect.

Here is my [log file](https://github.com/pgyogesh/python/blob/master/ErrorLog.txt):

Could someone please help me in this?

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Please don' t link to code files. Try to put the relevant code directly in your question. This way everyone can quickly get a grip on your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: " end line(2084) is incorrect." - what would correct be?

Comment: @MrLeeh Thanks. I have edited my question.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It should be 2418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're enumerating over the open file without rewinding it, so line numbers aren't correct anymore. You could use `input_file.seek(0)` to do that, but there're simpler ways. Something like this might work (dry-coded, YMMV) for the main loop - and in addition, it only reads through the file once.

```
with open(vLogFile) as input_file, open(output_file, 'a') as output_file:
    do_write = False
    for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
        if i == 1:  # First line, so figure out the start/end markers
            vDate = vline[0:10]
            start_line = vDate + ' ' + start_time
            end_line = vDate + ' ' +end_time
        if not do_write and line.startswith(start_line):  # If we need to start copying...
            do_write = True
            print('Starting to write from line %d', i)
        if do_write:
            output_file.write(line)
        if line.startswith(end_line):  # Stop writing, we have everything
            print('Stopping write on line %d', i)
            break
```

Comment: Perfect... You are my hero :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a good use for [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) and [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.strptime("16:16", "%H:%M")
end_time = datetime.strptime("16:29", "%H:%M")

with open('ErrorLog.txt') as f_log, open('trimmed.txt', 'w') as f_trimmed:
    for row in itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[11:16], "%H:%M") < start_time, f_log):
        f_trimmed.write(row)
        break

    for row in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[11:16], "%H:%M") < end_time, f_log):
        f_trimmed.write(row)
```

This would give you an output `trimmed.txt` as follows:

```
2017-11-12 16:16:16.642 Info: Forest Extensions state changed from open to start closing because shutting down
2017-11-12 16:16:16.642 Info: Database Extensions is offline
2017-11-12 16:16:16.643 Info: Forest Extensions state changed from start closing to middle closing because shutting down
.
.
2017-11-12 16:24:07.161 Info: Deleted 1 MB at 345 MB/sec /Users/yogeshjadhav96/Library/Application Support/MarkLogic/Data/Forests/App-Services/000001db
2017-11-12 16:24:07.165 Info: Deleted 10 MB at 2361 MB/sec /Users/yogeshjadhav96/Library/Application Support/MarkLogic/Data/Forests/App-Services/000001dc
```

This has the effect of filtering out lines that don't match the starting requirement i.e. too early, and to then only read lines until the ending requirement. Each `row` is read in and a lambda function is used to extract the time, convert it into a `datetime` object and compare it with `start_time` or `end_time` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give try to this as well.